# Erlang - starting VM'/Nodes with accompanying command

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am in the process of testing a small system.

It is very time consuming each time I make a change because I need to:

1. Start 4 Erlang Nodes/Vms with specific names
2. Run a single line of code on each of them

   - messenger:start_server().
   - messenger:start_router().
   - messenger:logon(steven).
   - messenger:logon(dave).

Each one of those lines is executed on a different node.

Is there anyway I can automate things? I was looking at boot scripts but I cannot find anything that is simple and relative to me

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create simple bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

NAME=node1
mkdir -p /tmp/$NAME
run_erl -daemon /tmp/$NAME /tmp/$NAME erl -sname $NAME -eval "ok = messenger:start_server()"

NAME=node2
mkdir -p /tmp/$NAME
run_erl -daemon /tmp/$NAME /tmp/$NAME erl -sname $NAME -eval "ok = messenger:start_router()"

NAME=node3
mkdir -p /tmp/$NAME
run_erl -daemon /tmp/$NAME /tmp/$NAME erl -sname $NAME -eval "ok = messenger:logon(steven)"

NAME=node4
mkdir -p /tmp/$NAME
run_erl -daemon /tmp/$NAME /tmp/$NAME erl -sname $NAME -eval "ok = messenger:logon(dave)."
```

All output from node you can find in `/tmp/nodeN` directory.
You can connect to the node with following bash command:

```
erl -sname 'test@your-host-name' -remsh 'nodeN@your-host-name'
```

You can find more info in [erl man](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) and [run_erl man](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/run_erl.html).

Comment: This seems great and will be useful, however (I should have mentioned) I am developing on a windows machine, is it as easy as something like this?

Comment: On Windows you can try [erlsrv](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlsrv.html) or [start_erl](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/start_erl.html) for releases.